# Extracting specific keyvalue in dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am learning to use Python and Twitter API. The information of a user was saved as json file.

Basically the json file stored a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}]
```

In each dictionary there are some information, f.ex.:

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2018-04-28 13:12:07", 
    "favorite_count": 0, 
    "followers_count": 2, 
    "id_str": "990217093206310912", 
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
    "retweet_count": 0, 
    "screen_name": "SyerahMizi", 
    "text": "u can count on me like 123 \ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\udc6d"
  }, 
  {
    "created_at": "2018-04-26 04:21:48", 
    "favorite_count": 0, 
    "followers_count": 2, 
    "id_str": "989358860937846785", 
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
    "retweet_count": 0, 
    "screen_name": "SyerahMizi", 
    "text": "Never give up"
  }, 
]
```

I am simply trying to print only the "text" information in each dictionary but I kept getting an error

```py
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Here is what I have so far:

```py
import json
    with open('981452637_tweetlist.json') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        lst = json_file['text'][0]
        print lst
```

so any help or explanation as to what I need would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for-loop.

```
for d in json_data:
    print(d["text"])
```

If you wanted it on the same line, you can instead make a list and append to it in the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

As error is suggesting, list indices must be 'int' not 'str'. You are mistakenly taking list as dictionary and dictionary as list. Correct code will be:

```
import json
    with open('981452637_tweetlist.json') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        lst = json_file[0]['text']              #change here
        print lst
```